# Switch case, check ranges in C# 3.5

Tags: c#, switch-statement

In C#, the `switch` statement doesn't allow cases to span ranges of values. I don't like the idea of using if-else loops for this purpose, so are there any other ways to check numeric ranges in C#?

Comment: You can't really do it in C# (unless it's a small range of numbers you can list in blocks), but, for once, you **can** in VB.Net - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009902/select-case-to-check-range-of-a-decimal-number funnily enough

Comment: Well you can have a method returning bool which takes in the range and then if loops, its simple, readable and does the work well

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68578/multiple-cases-in-switch
You cannot do this in C#. Check the answer above.

Comment: **Important note** : Ranges are supported in switch case starting C# v7 - [Switch case: can I use a range instead of a one number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20147879/465053). So, if you feel like better upgrade from C# v3.5 to v7 instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a `HashTable` respectively `Dictionary` to create a mapping of `Condition => Action`.

Example:

```
class Programm
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var myNum = 12;

        var cases = new Dictionary<Func<int, bool>, Action>
        { 
            { x => x < 3 ,    () => Console.WriteLine("Smaller than 3")   } ,
            { x => x < 30 ,   () => Console.WriteLine("Smaller than 30")  } ,
            { x => x < 300 ,  () => Console.WriteLine("Smaller than 300") } 
        };

        cases.First(kvp => kvp.Key(myNum)).Value();
    }
}
```

This technique is a general alternative to `switch`, especially if the actions consists only of one line (like a method call).

And if you're a fan of type aliases:

```
using Int32Condition = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Func<System.Int32, System.Boolean>, System.Action>;
...
    var cases = new Int32Condition()
    { 
        { x => x < 3 ,    () => Console.WriteLine("Smaller than 3")   } ,
        { x => x < 30 ,   () => Console.WriteLine("Smaller than 30")  } ,
        { x => x < 300 ,  () => Console.WriteLine("Smaller than 300") } 
    };
```

Comment: But you should not take a dictionary (take a list of KeyValuePair, Tuple or sth self defined) otherwise you can't predict in which order the Funcs are called for testing.

Comment: Interesting but if I saw this pattern as a replacement of if/else in real project I'm submitting it to http://thedailywtf.com :)

Comment: This solution is outright ridiculous.  Good for a quiz, but very bad for production code.  It is slow, as it wastes memory, and causes too much calls which cannot be inlined.

Comment: This code doesn't even *work*.  Since a dictionary is inierently unordered you can't be sure that `x < 3` will be checked before `x < 30`.  That it does in one or two tests cases doesn't mean it will hold true.  A `Dictionary` is simply the wrong data structure here, unless you ensure that the methods can be called in any order (which you haven't done).  As mentinoed by Oliver, a list of tuples would be one way to ensure ordering, and is semantically correct.  Note that this isn't really any different than a series of `if/else if` statements either.

Answer (score 5):

Nope. Of course, if the ranges are small you could use the

```
case 4:
case 5:
case 6:
   // blah
   break;
```

approach, but other than that: no. Use `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 4):

if the interval of the ranges is constant, you can try

```
        int num = 11;
        int range = (num - 1) / 10; //here interval is 10
        switch (range)
        {
            case 0:
                Console.Write("1-10");
                break; // 1-10
            case 1:
                Console.Write("11-20");
                break; // 11-20
            // etc...
        }
```

Output would be: `"11-20"`
if interval is variable then use `if/else`

Answer (score 1):

No. At least nothing which is more beautiful.

Also there is no C# 3.5 only .NET 3.5 and C# 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
 private void ExecuteInRange(Dictionary<Range,Action<int>> ranges)
    {
        foreach (var range in ranges)
        {
            if (range.Key.Value < range.Key.Max && range.Key.Value > range.Key.Max)
                range.Value(range.Key.Value);
        }
    }


public class Range
{
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        int b;
        b = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);

        int ans = (100-b)/3; //the 3 represents the interval
        //100 represents the last number


        switch(ans)
        {

           case 0:
                MessageBox.Show("98 to 100");
           break;

           case 1:
                MessageBox.Show("95 to 97");
           break;

           case 2:
                MessageBox.Show("92 to 94");
           break;

           case 3:
                MessageBox.Show("89 to 91");
           break;

           case 4:
                MessageBox.Show("86 to 88");
           break;

           default:
                MessageBox.Show("out of range");
           break;
```

Answer (score -1):

A sort of nested-shorthand if-else thing works, and is clean.

```
myModel.Value = modelResult >= 20 ? 5 : modelResult >= 14 ? 4 : modelResult >= 5 ? 3 : modelResult >= 2 ? 2 : modelResult == 1 ? 1 : 0;
```