# How to build a ranged switch case expression at runtime?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, expression, expression-trees

I am building a Switch expression to match ranges of integers at runtime.
Currently I am able to compile and run the equivalent of the following using `Expression.SwitchCase`:

```
switch(value)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("1 or 2");
        break;
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
        Console.WriteLine("3, 4 or 5");
        break;
}
```

My issue being - I have to create a SwitchCase for every constant in the range I wish to match:

`Expression.SwitchCase(body, Expression.Constant(1))`

`Expression.SwitchCase(body, Expression.Constant(2))`

Is there a more concise way to achieve this? Is there a way I can replace that constant expression with an expression that evaluates the switched value against a range?. Performance is also of interest, especially if the range is large.

Comment: Have you looked at this question [switch-case-can-i-use-a-range-instead-of-a-one-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147879/switch-case-can-i-use-a-range-instead-of-a-one-number)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the result I want to achieve, but I want to know if it is possible to build at runtime using expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code with other overload of [`Expression.SwitchCase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.switchcase?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_SwitchCase_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression__)

Just create an array with a test values and convert it to `ConstantExpression`. Try this example:

```
var writeLine = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] {typeof(string)});

// body of first block
var action1 = Expression.Call(writeLine, Expression.Constant("1 or 2"));
// body of second block
var action2 = Expression.Call(writeLine, Expression.Constant("3, 4 or 5"));

var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "value");
var body = Expression.Switch(value,
    Expression.SwitchCase(
      action1,
      new[] {1, 2}.Select(i => Expression.Constant(i))),
    Expression.SwitchCase(
      action2, 
      new[] {3, 4, 5}.Select(i => Expression.Constant(i)))
);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<int>>(body, value);
var method = lambda.Compile();

method(1); // print "1 or 2"
method(4); // print "3, 4 or 5"
```