# Multiple numbers in one case

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for a switch statement code that can do this.

```
if (value2 > 0)
{
    button2.Visible = true;
    button3.Visible = false;
    button4.Visible = false;
    listBox2.Items.Add("Black");
}
if (value2 < 0)
{
    button2.Visible = false;
    button3.Visible = false;
    button4.Visible = true;
    listBox2.Items.Add("Red");
}
if (value2 == 0)
{
    button2.Visible = false;
    button3.Visible = true;
    button4.Visible = false;
    listBox2.Items.Add("Green");
}
```

Or better, If value2 is anywhere between -9 to -1, 0 and 1 to 9.
Is there a way I can do it in 3 cases so I don't need to write 21 cases for 21 numbers?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you've shown?

Comment: Why do you need a switch statement if you already have a working if-statement? Btw, I would use if-else, so in case one is true, the others don't have to be evaluated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch case: can I use a range instead of a one number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147879/switch-case-can-i-use-a-range-instead-of-a-one-number)

Comment: @simonatrcl nothing I want I want to learn something new and If-else seems like a boring code for me to use all the time

Comment: @DragandDrop Thanks Just what I needed!

Comment: @RMWTH ah ok, cool :)

Comment: When you want to lern something you could also read about enum flags and how and when to use them. 8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want I want to learn something new and If-else seems like a boring
> code for me to use all the time – RMWTH

You could condense it all down to one block:

```
button2.Visible = (value2 > 0);
button3.Visible = (value2 == 0);
button4.Visible = (value2 < 2);
listBox2.Items.Add((value2 > 0) ? "Black" : ((value2 < 0) ? "Red" : "Green"))
```