# When I click the button, the Select Case will not do anything

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Stack Overflow.
I am working on making a brackets program. And I want to be able to use `Select Case` for it to tell be who would win.

I have made the following code:

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim gen1 As New System.Random
        Dim random As Integer
        Dim B1 As String
        random = gen1.Next(0, 101)
        Select Case B1
            Case random <= 50
                MessageBox.Show("less than or = to 50")
            Case random >= 51
                MessageBox.Show("More than or = to 51")
        End Select
    End Sub
```

But when I click the button, the code does not do anything. No message boxes appear, no anything. What could be wrong in this code?
I have set up the random generator code correctly by using the `Dim gen1 As New System.Random`, and the `Dim random As Integer`, but nothing happens. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select case to check range of a decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009902/select-case-to-check-range-of-a-decimal-number)

Comment: You probably want `Select Case random`. Then `Case Is <= 50` etc. If you set `Option Strict On`, you'll have an instant clue of what's wrong.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you use B1 to start the select and then use another variable for your cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the B1 variable to anything.  If you modify the code to be something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim gen1 As New System.Random
    Dim random As Integer
    Dim B1 As String

    random = gen1.Next(0, 101)
    Select Case random
        Case Is <= 50
            MessageBox.Show("less than or = to 50")
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("More than or = to 51")
    End Select
End Sub
```

You can find some more information here [Select Case Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement)

You could rewrite it to use an If statement instead

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim gen1 As New System.Random

    if gen1.Next(0, 101) <= 50 then
        MessageBox.Show("less than or = to 50")
    else
        MessageBox.Show("More than or = to 51")
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be better to declare the Random class outside of the Sub. It is seeded with the system time and if the button is clicked again quickly you can get the same "random" number".